# How do I list classes with a SQL query on OrientDB?

Tags: sql, orientdb

On [orientdb documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Console-Command-Classes.html) I found a command like LIST CLASSES or CLASSES that returns a list of current classes in the database  -->

```
    orientdb> LIST CLASSES

    CLASSES
    -------------+------+-------------+-----------
     NAME        |  ID  | CLUSTERS    | ELEMENTS  
    -------------+------+-------------+-----------
     Person      |    0 | person      |         7 
     Animal      |    1 | animal      |         5 
     AnimalRace  |    2 | AnimalRace  |         0 
     AnimalType  |    3 | AnimalType  |         1 
     OrderItem   |    4 | OrderItem   |         0 
     Order       |    5 | Order       |         0 
     City        |    6 | City        |         3 
    -------------+------+-------------+-----------
     TOTAL                                     16 
    -----------------------------------------------
    .
```

I am trying to load all database with select * from V and later trying to filter all results by @class, but I don't think this is a good idea when the database gets big...

**Is there a way to get the same result with a SQL query?**

Comment: Why do you think filtering by a field is not a good idea when the database gets big?

Comment: because i must to load and fill my ram memory with all database and later compare it with some array that save class names.. i think could be more efficient with just one native command on database that simply reads some index and give me an answer (no big loads on ram)

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

```
SELECT expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it works but when i do something like --> 
SELECT expand(classes) from metadata:schema where superClasses = "V"
it gives an empty answer... i try too --> SELECT expand(classes) from metadata:schema where name = "OTriggered"
and still empty answer... :(

Comment: Use these queries: ```SELECT from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where name = "OTriggered"``` and ```SELECT from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where "V" in superClasses```